# Awk multiline change

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have the following file for datadog

```
########################################
## System Probe Network Configuration ##
########################################

# network_config:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Set to true to enable the Network Module of the System Probe
  #
  # enabled: falseee



##########################################
## Security Agent Runtime Configuration ##
##                                      ##
## Settings to sent logs to Datadog are ##
## fetched from section `logs_config`   ##
##########################################

# runtime_security_config:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## @env DD_RUNTIME_SECURITY_CONFIG_ENABLED - boolean - optional -
default: false
  ## Set to true to enable Cloud Workload Security (CWS).
  #
  # enabled: falseee
```

and i essentially want to turn the following portion ..

```
########################################
## System Probe Network Configuration ##
########################################

# network_config:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Set to true to enable the Network Module of the System Probe
  #
  # enabled: falseee
```

into this

```
########################################
## System Probe Network Configuration ##
########################################

# network_config:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Set to true to enable the Network Module of the System Probe
  #
  # enabled: TRUE
```

Being that there are multiple lines with enabled:false in the file i am using a multiline awk search to do my searching but i am stuck because i cant seem to get past actually making the changes to the overall file...

i have created a search pattern from

```
alias start="# network_config:"
alias end="# enabled: falseee"
```

I then try to do the following by cutting out the portion that i want using awk...

```
main=$(awk "/$start/, /$end/" system.yaml)
```

and then the part i actually want to switch...

```
sub_value=$(awk "/$start/, /$end/" system.yaml | awk '{sub(/enabled: falseee/,"enabled: TRUE"); print}')
```

so now i have tried doing the following to switch this on the whole file.. but it just doesnt seem to work....

```
echo $file | awk -v srch="$main" -v repl="$sub_value" '{ sub(srch,repl,$0); print $0 }'
```

or even

```
echo "$(awk 'awk "{sub(/$(awk "/$start/, /$end/" system.yaml)/, $sub_value); print}"' system.yaml)" > newFile
```

the reason i want to do this using awk is because we use tanium at work, and im not sure how this file is configured for all our servers.  So i just want to change that chunk of the file for every server by running a script through tanium... I guess im just getting lost in the sauce with awk.. Can anyone give me a clue as to what im missing and not seeing?

Comment: `alias` is only applied where the shell is expecting a command. It does not alias plain text. You just define a variable when you want data substitution.

Answer (score 0):

If [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) is allowed:

```
perl -00pe 's/(# network_config.*?enabled: )falseee/$1true/s' file
```

### Output

```
########################################
## System Probe Network Configuration ##
########################################

# network_config:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Set to true to enable the Network Module of the System Probe
  #
  # enabled: true
```

If you want to edit *in-place*, add `-i` switch:

```
perl -i -00pe .....
```

Comment: Im not sure it has perl, is perl part of regular unix?

Comment: No, but all Linux have Perl (AFAIK)

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the exact initial text, and at least one blank line between blocks:

```
awk '/# network_config:/,NF==0 { sub ("falseee", "TRUE") } { print }'
```

The `sub()` will silently do nothing except on the required line.

Answer (score 0):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/^# network_config:/,/enabled: falseee/s/enabled: falseee/enabled: TRUE/'
```

Explanation:

1. `/^# network_config:/,/enabled: falseee/` - will use the addressing
   feature in `sed`, and will search a section that begins with a line
   that starts with `# network_config:` and ends with a line that
   includes `enabled: falseee`.
2. `s/enabled: falseee/enabled: TRUE/` - This part will work only inside the section specified by the addressing, and change `enabled: falseee` to `enabled: TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/# network_config:/{f=1} f && /# enabled/{sub(/falseee/,"TRUE"); f=0} 1' file
########################################
## System Probe Network Configuration ##
########################################

# network_config:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## Set to true to enable the Network Module of the System Probe
  #
  # enabled: TRUE



##########################################
## Security Agent Runtime Configuration ##
##                                      ##
## Settings to sent logs to Datadog are ##
## fetched from section `logs_config`   ##
##########################################

# runtime_security_config:
  ## @param enabled - boolean - optional - default: false
  ## @env DD_RUNTIME_SECURITY_CONFIG_ENABLED - boolean - optional -
default: false
  ## Set to true to enable Cloud Workload Security (CWS).
  #
  # enabled: falseee
```